# Unable to install packages with pip in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip, python-import

I am trying to install `Flask` with the following command:

`pip install flask`

But pip returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=3.0.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.1.2 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.1.2 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.1.3 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker>=1.6.2 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from flask) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/john/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.1.2->flask) (2.1.1)
```

(I have anaconda and conda installed)

My imports show an error:

[image: (Error Image)]

All that my code contains is:

```py
from flask import *
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems to be a configuration issue with the IDE you are using. I expect that if you actually run the script from the command line, the imports resolve correctly. Could you please share more details about your IDE?

Comment: I am using VS code, but have also tried to install flask through the command `python -m pip install flask`  in the system terminal

Comment: hi @JohnCarter.   make sure that you are running the current version of python in the IDE.  bottom right hand corner to select python version...

Comment: Yes, thank you @D.L, I have tried changing the python interpreter but still to no avail. All of them return the same error.

Comment: Hey @D.L, could you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have anaconda then you should use `conda install <package>`.

If you have downloaded python from the web on the https://www.python.org website (which is what I did), then you should be using `python -m pip install <package>`.

I believe that the general rule is this:

> Be careful when mixing conda and pip packages, as you can sometimes get dependency conflicts. In general use conda where possible, and pip for packages not available from conda channels.

Answer (score 0):

Pip installing something and it not being recognised is (as far as I know) always a symptom of mismatching python executables. The python you're using to run a file might be different from the python you're using to execute the script, and that one might be different from the one your IDE is using to check if the imports exist.

You appear to have already done this in the comments, but the first step is to pip install via the python executable:

```bash
python -m pip install --update flask
```

After this, everything should be installed, and should work when you execute the files from the same command line like:

```bash
python file.py
```

However, your IDE might still disagree at this point (the editor shows an error, even tough the code runs fine), which means that the IDE is using a different python interpreter than you are from the console (even your IDE's console).

To fix this, and any of these issues, you should select the right intepreter (find it with `which python`) in your IDE. On visual studio code, The interpreter selection is here (Screenshot editied in by D.L.):

[image]

Comment: agree with all said, aside from the usage of [virtual environments venv](https://youtu.be/dUO83qlzOyw) .

Comment: Do not recommend to use `venv` when OP has anaconda

Comment: Oops, hadn't seen that OP had annaconda. I'll edit that out.

Comment: @Egeau, thank you for responding but the command `python -m pip install --update flask` returns: 
```Usage:   
 /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
 /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options]
  /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install [options][-e]<vcs project url>
  /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install [options][-e]<local project path>
  /home/john/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install [options]<archive url/path>
no such option: --update```

Comment: (I have already tried `which python` and it returns `/home/john/anaconda3/bin/python` . I tried to turn on that interpreter and the same bug occurs.)

Comment: I'm sorry, it's `upgrade` not `update`

Comment: As for VSCode still showing the stuff is not installed if you have the right envoirement selected, I don't know how to deal with that, as that'd be a VSCode issue, and I'm a vim user myself.